# python executing both if and else statement

Tags: python

I have the problem that python us executing both if and else statement together

Please watch pic
[Pic of indent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtVhu.png)

I tried 'if not' and indendent the else but nothing seems to work.

Here is a part of my script. Im litte new to this so i would appreciate the help.

What i want to do is read if there is a 255.255.255.252 in the cofig. (this works and does change the config accordingly) But if there is no  255.255.255.252 there should be a print in my log.

the result is : (it does both)

2017-10-26 15:39:29,350 dailer 1 off IP testrouter is completed
2017-10-26 15:39:29,351 dailer 1 off IP lprm1212 has no /30

```
       for my_output in result0.split("\n"):
            if len(my_output) !=0:
                if  my_output.find("255.255.255.252") != -1:
                    print (my_output)
                    tn.read_until('')
                    tn.write("config terminal"+"\n")
                    tn.read_until("(config)#")
                    tn.write("interface Dialer1"+"\n")
                    tn.read_until("(config-if)#")
                    tn.write("description test"+"\n")
                    tn.write("end"+"\n")
                    logger.debug('dailer 1 off IP ' + host2login + ' is completed')
                 else:
                     logger.debug('dailer 1 off IP ' + host2login + ' has no /30')
             else:
                 logger.debug('dailer 1 off IP ' + host2login + ' has no /30')
        else:
            logger.debug('dailer 1 off IP ' + host2login + ' has no /30')
```

Comment: It doesn't really make sense having a nested if if you don't have a nested else. Just collapse them. Also please fix your indentation.

Comment: if your code is exactly as I see the else is outside the for. do align the else with the if. by the way, the else corresponds to the first if ?

Comment: without proper indentation there is no way to tell what the else is even supposed to do. Is it for the inner if, the outer if or the loop itself?

Comment: The else indendent is directly under the for statement. Could not get it right on the website here.

Comment: @fnitty: Unfortunately indendation does matter in Python. Neither your original post nor your edit are correct so I cannot understand what it should be

Comment: You could join both checks in an `&` manner

Comment: Its not the indendation. In my scripts its oke. I did a eddit. Still comes my output is double and it even loops.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)).  By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Comment: You may want to change the text printed in the three levels of else to see what exactly your code is doing. Also look [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) up to understand how `for--else` works.

Answer (score 3):

You have the indentation all over the place. If and else have to be on the same indentation like so:

```
for my_output in result0.split("\n"):
    if len(my_output) !=0:
        if  my_output.find("255.255.255.252") != -1:
            print (my_output)
            tn.read_until('')
            tn.write("config terminal"+"\n")
            tn.read_until("(config)#")
            tn.write("interface Dialer1"+"\n")
            tn.read_until("(config-if)#")
            tn.write("description test"+"\n")
            tn.write("end"+"\n")
            logger.debug('dailer 1 off IP ' + host2login + ' is completed')
        else:
            logger.debug('dailer 1 off IP ' + host2login + ' has no /30')
```

In this case, your else belongs to the second if, while the first if does not have a else case.

Comment: please look pic

Comment: In your updated code sample you have tried to have an else case that corresponds to a for loop. That does not work. Python does not know what to do with it. Only if's have else's. Your bottom if is the problem.

Comment: Thankt but this doenst solve the problem stil get them both. 

2017-10-26 16:19:45,115 dailer 1 off IP lprm1212 has no /30
2017-10-26 16:19:45,351 dailer 1 off IP lprm1212 is completed

Comment: on another note (looking at your pic): you still have the indentation wrong. code after else should come one line below and 4 spaces to the right. :) hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is indentation , if(s) and else(s) which relate to each other "MUST" be in the same indentation level :

```
# code
if x<0:
    # do something
else:
    # do something else
# code
```

Comment: i did please look pic

Comment: You have more 2 if and 3 else the third else is ignored .